# Trackpy: How to remove unwanted particles

Tags: python, image-processing, detection, particles, trackpy

I have an image that I want to detect bright spots. I can detect particles according to the characteristics I want. but when linking these particles I found, I can't eliminate unwanted particles.
The line of code that detects the particles is as follows.

```
f = tp.batch(frame_list[:],7, invert = False,
         minmass = 15, maxsize = 17, preprocess = False)

t = tp.link_df(f,3, memory =5)
```

there are particles that are detected only in 1 image and then not visible. I don't want them.Shouldn't the 2nd parameter in t variable do this job? even if she doesn't, I can loop it and find it again.but this will force the program. Because we have 550 thousand lines yield.How can I deal with this? I checked the library, but nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using pd.Dataframe. maybe I'm writing here in case someone needs it. The tp.batch function returns a pd dataframe.

```
for particle in df["particle"].unique():

       calculations...

    for i in range(len(x)-1):

       calculations...

if len(x) >= 3  :
```